# Asp.net mvc how to change the default label text in @html.labelfor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So using annotations my default label for a field is 
`[Display(Name = "Spent")]`

But of course depending on the context the field is displayed in I would like to change it in the View to say "Spent $".

For the label, MVC5 scaffolding generates...
`@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Spend Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })`

and so the label is "Spent".

How can I make it "Spent $" in the view..??

Comment: why don't ypu change DisplayName attribute

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use this overloaded **[`LabelFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833698(v=vs.118).aspx)** method

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SpendAmount, "Spent $", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Comment: I tried to vote up but I needed 15 reputations. Can anyone give me a reputation please. I am a very experienced programmer in many areas but not ASP.NET in general.

Comment: It is enough to me to accept my answer as solution :)